# Information for the Variance of a Normal Distribution

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, fisher-information

I have a question studying Hogg&Craig Introduction to Mathematical Statistics, 7th edition, in page 354.
[image]

I don't know where I got wrong. Please Check. Thank you.

Comment: There appear to be multiple errors in differentiation.  Recompute $d\left(\frac{1}{2\nu^2}\right)/d\nu$.

Comment: Please avoid posting questions as images (for example, vision-impaired readers using text-to-speech will have no sense of what's there). Since you appear to be familiar with LaTeX, please see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ... Further note that "please check" is not a question; please try to write a specific question

Comment: @whuber Sorry for the misplaced question, But I differentiated $d\left(\frac{1}{2\nu^2}\right)/d\nu$ well. It's $\frac{-1}{ \nu^3}$.

Comment: Fair enough: your question deserves to stand.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the second derivative of the log is incorrect. It should be:

$ \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial (\sigma^2)^2}\log L(x_1| \mu, \sigma^2)   = \frac{1}{2\sigma^4} - \frac{1}{\sigma^6}(x_1 - \mu)^2 $

When taking the Expectation, recall that $E(x - \mu)^2 = \sigma^2$ from which the final result is easy to obtain if you are careful with the signs.